# Finding a sub tree in a forest

Tags: neo4j

I am new to neo4j and trying to build a proof of concept for a project. My basic question is, given a graph, if I select a root node how do I find all sub nodes that sit below it in the graph. I don't want to return any parent nodes

I have been looking at some of the apoc functions but without success.

e.g

```
MATCH (x{id:1})
CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(x,{relationshipFilter:'PARENT[>]'}) YIELD nodes, 
relationships
RETURN nodes, relationships
```

or

```
MATCH (x{id:1})
CALL apoc.path.subgraphNodes(x,{relationshipFilter:'[<]PARENT'}) YIELD node
RETURN node
```

which I would expect to work but I am obviously mis-understanding something conceptually.

In the following test case

```
CREATE (r:root)
FOREACH (i IN range(1,5)|
         CREATE (r)-[:PARENT]->(c:child { id:i }));


MATCH (c:child)
     FOREACH (j IN range(1,5)|
        CREATE (c)-[:PARENT]->(:child { id:c.id*10+j }));

MATCH (c:child)
     FOREACH (j IN range(1,5)|
        CREATE (c)-[:PARENT]->(:child { id:c.id*10+j }));
```

if I want to set the root node to node 5 I am trying to return 5,51,52,53,54,55, then all sub nodes as well, eg. 511 through to 555

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one, you should always use labels in your queries (as it allows you to use an index for lookup, if you've created an index on the given label + property / properties).

Otherwise, the query looks ALMOST right, except there's a small problem in your relationship filter:

`relationshipFilter:'[<]PARENT'` The brackets around the direction aren't needed. In the documentation, they are there to denote that the direction is optional, but the brackets themselves should not be literally included.

Try this:

```
MATCH (x:child {id:1})
CALL apoc.path.subgraphNodes(x,{relationshipFilter:'<PARENT'}) YIELD node
RETURN node
```